# Script tries to create files even though it shouldn't have to?

Tags: shell-script, files, test, mkdir

I have a folder which contains some folders, these folder are moved very often so I made a script to see if they exist, and if not then create them. This is what I did to (which I though would) achieve it:

```
if [ ! -f "$DIR/0folder" ]
then
mkdir "$DIR/0folder"
fi
```

But, even if `0folder` already exists, it still tries to make it which `mkdir` tells me. Like here;

```
mkdir: /Allfoldersgoeshere/subfolder/0folder: File exists
```

Why? It should just ignore it because it already exists?

Comment: Have you tried to replace `-f` by `-d`?

Comment: THe simpel answer is `mkdir -p "$dir/0folder"`  It will create if it doesn't exist otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: @val0x00ff: That should be an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-f` in your test is checking if *`FILE` exists and is a regular file*.
What you need is `-d` to test if *`FILE` exists and is a directory*.

```
if [ ! -d "$DIR/0folder" ]
then
mkdir "$DIR/0folder"
fi
```

It is not mandatory to check if a directory exists though.  According to the man page of `mkdir` we see the following

```
man mkdir | grep -A1 -- -p

   -p, --parents
          no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

However, if *`FILE` exists and is a regular file* `mkdir -p` will fail with

```
mkdir: /Allfoldersgoeshere/subfolder/0folder': Not a directory.
```

In this scenario handling the `file` that is expected to be a `directory` will be necessary before directory creation.

Comment: Oh, so `-f` is for files and `-d` for directories?

Comment: Yes, `man test` will show the `test` options.

Comment: And if you don't care what sort of thing it is, you can use `-e`.

Comment: @val0x00ff - Thank you for adding the `mkdir -p` info.

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (`man bash`) under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS:

```
-f file
          True if file exists and is a regular file.

-d file
          True if file exists and is a directory.
```

So, to check for the existence of a directory (not a file)...

```
if [[ ! -d "$DIR/0folder" ]] ; then
    mkdir "$DIR/0folder"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Neither `-d` or `-f` is useful here for robust tests - because they're just opposite sides of the same coin.

```
touch file; [ ! -d file ] && mkdir file
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘file’: File exists
```

See? Better would be `[ -e ... ] || mkdir ...` to check for *existence*, which would at least save on the error above, but even that has its issues - like race conditions or not creating parents as needed or unresolved symlinks.

```
if    [ ! -e "$DIR/0folder" ] && 
      [ ! -L "$DIR/0folder" ] 
then  mkdir -- "$DIR/0folder"
fi
```

...is closer but still racy and still assumes all parents exist as well.

Probably you could work out a sure `test` if you needed to, but you really don't. You can get atomic directory creation w/ `mkdir -p` and test its return. There aren't too many standard shell tools which offer atomic fs ops - it's best we take advantage of those that do.

Comment: +1 for presenting a more complete answer and explanation than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Read the manual. The -p option will make a directory and intermediate directories as required if it doesn't exist or silently fail. Assuming that you are not processing thousands of files then you could just do `mkdir -p "${DIR}/0folder` or if you feel the need to test then

```
 [ -d "${DIR}/0folder" ] || mkdir -p "${DIR}/0folder"
```

Comment: The `-d` test before `mkdir -p` is rather useless. If it is useful to know whether or not a directory was created, just test `mkdir` exit status: `0` means a directory was created. That said. +1 for `mkdir -p`... to nullify the notification when exit status is non-zero, `mkdir -p dir/dir 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @Peter.O - possibly worse than useless - it implies the test is useful, but it is not.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing: if the $DIR/0folder doesn't exist, make a directory with that name.

Just change -f (file) by -d (directory).

That should solve your problem, now you could be interested on some tips that people had given here but that is apart.